# php - как ограничить доступ к файлам через htaccess внешним юзерам

Tags: php, .htaccess

надобно бы лишить гостей возможности читать файлы логов в /log.txt и шаблонов /folder/* , однако не лишать возможности получать эти файлы самими php скриптами

Answer (score 2):

Запрет в апаче .htaccess:

```
<Files "log.txt">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Files>
```

PHP скрипты все еще могут читать эти файлы, запрет только вебсерверу

Запрет для юзеров:
сменить пользователя/группу файлов на те что использует апач
закрыть доступ для остальны: `chmod -R u=rwX,g=rX,o=` wwwfiles/*